# Jquery find all elements with text

Tags: jquery, text

What would be the best way to scan trough all the DOM, find any element that have text and wrap it in a span class?
Thanx

Comment: I think you need to specify what you mean with 'any element that have text'. Do you mean elements that contain text other than white space, but not in children elements?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To wrap all text nodes that contain something other than just whitespace:

```
$('body *').contents().filter(function() { 
    return (this.nodeType == 3) && this.nodeValue.match(/\S/); 
}).wrap("<span />")
```

To wrap all text nodes, including those that contain only whitespace:

```
$('body *').contents().filter(function() { 
    return (this.nodeType == 3) && this.nodeValue.length > 0; 
}).wrap("<span />")
```

Comment: See this code in action at: http://jsbin.com/oquhu3/3 (the one *with* whitespace)

Comment: Thanx, it works! I've tryed to add a class but it did not work.
$(function() {
  $('body *').contents().filter(function() {
    return (this.nodeType == 3) && this.nodeValue.length > 0;
  }).addClass("someclass");
});

Any idea why?
Thanx again.

Comment: You can't add a class to a text node. Try wrapping it with a span that has a class:  $('body *').contents().filter(function() { 
    return (this.nodeType == 3) && this.nodeValue.length > 0; 
}).wrap("<span class='someclass' />")

Comment: Hmmm, I've did it anyway by making a variable and adding a parent class. Thanx guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.each** to iterate over all elememnts:

```
$('*').each(function(){
    if($(this).text())
    {
        $(this).wrapInner('<span />');
    }
})
```

I didn't test that piece of code but it is quite simple. All you need to learn about is **.each**, **wrapInner** and * selector. jQuery docs is pretty helpful here.

Comment: try to add $(document).ready(); to your code: $(document).ready(function(){
$('*').each(function{}(
    if($(this).text())
    {
        $(this).wrapInner('<span />');
    }
))

})

Comment: I think that this will add class to all HTML elements regardless if they have or not actual text.

Comment: @Dzida: yes, how silly of me. But you have other errors in your code, you have switched {} an () in your anonymous function... When that is fixed it seems to work.

Comment: @Mircea seems to be right (I tested it)... There are a lot of spans added to the DOM with this method.