# How to turn keyword on a site into links with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, keyword

I'm trying to turn a set of keywords into links on my site. I am currently using this code which will turn one keyword into a link. However, now I want to expand it to have several words. The link will always be the same, however, the keyword changes, so the link text must also reflect that.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
  var thePage = $("body");
  thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/Wedding Stationery/ig, '<a class="discrete" href="http://www.kateguest.com">wedding stationery</a>'));
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

How can I expand this to use 5 or 6 keywords?

Comment: You will have to define an array of terms to search against. Then, you'll have to loop over the array and check for the keyword's existence on the page, then perform the replace.

Comment: A good start would be to not use regex to modify raw HTML

Comment: @mplungjan I'm afraid I don't know what that means

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery find all elements with text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091360/jquery-find-all-elements-with-text)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of 
[How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the replacement in a loop. You can use `$&` in the replacement to refer to the text that was matched.

```
var keywords = ['wedding stationery', 'something else', 'other keyword'];
var thePage = $("body");
var theHtml = thePage.html();
for (i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    theHtml = theHtml.replace(new RegExp(keywords[i], 'ig'),
                '<a class="discrete" href="http://www.kateguest.com">$&</a>');
}
thePage.html(theHtml);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/S6d54/4/)

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I'm afraid this didn't work for me though, didn't make any changes to my words

Comment: Fixed two problems. It should be `RegExp` and `$&`. I added a jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
var keywordsArray = ["place", "all", "of the", "keywords in here like this"];
var thePage = $("body");

for (var i = 0; i < keywordsArray.length; i++) {
    thePage.find(":contains("+keywordsArray[i]+")").each(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        var content = _this.html();
        content.replace(keywordsArray[i], '<a href="discrete" href="http://whateveryouwant.com/">' + keywordsArray[i] + '</a>');

        _this.html(content);
    });
};
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't appear to work. Didn't change any of the keywords

Comment: You need to edit the code so that it fits your keywords. If you read it you'll see how.

Comment: apologies, yes I had done that, and still nothing do I need to wrap it in $(document).ready(function() {??? I'm a bit of a newbie with jQuery

Comment: If you don't use a RegExp as the argument to `replace()` it only replaces the first occurrence, not all of them. You need to use an RE to get a global replace.