# Enlarge font-size in % for all texts with single rule?

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-size

I work with e-shop engine where lot of text-styles are defined in pixels directly (each element - own ruler), not in relative units. Now customer ask me to enlarge all the texts (texts, labels, titles and such) on 10%.
I don't want to go throw ALL the styles and write individual new rules for each element.

So **I am looking for some solution which can enlarge font-size for all elements with simple rules in CSS, or, if it's impossible JQuery**

I tried to use in CSS rule 
`* { font-size: 110% !important; }` 
but it works recursively (ancestor -> child -> child - each level +10%) so some text elements which have several ancestors became realy huge.

Comment: have a look at @font-face

Comment: You've already programmed yourself into a corner by using px in the first place. You're in for a big CSS refactor.

Comment: Adam 'Sacki' Sackfield, can you explain your idea?

Comment: Take a look at this post [FONT SIZING WITH REM](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)

Comment: Diodeus, it wasn't me, it was the template developer, and it's best seller template: Shoppica2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i used this code from [Lukasz Dziedzia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091360/jquery-find-all-elements-with-text) to get all the text in the page.

Now we use `$(this).css({ "font-size":($(this).css("font-size").replace('px','')*1.1 + "px"});` to change the `font-size` of each element.

Notice the use of `replace('px','');`, this is used here because `$(this).css("font-size")` returns the value with the letters "px" at the end. So after removing these 2 letters we can do the math : `$(this).css("font-size").replace('px','')*1.1`.

This is better than the first answer :)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQsnk/4/

Comment: look i did not test the answer, i'm working on this now i will edit my answer in after a while :)

Comment: Now look at the answer :)

Comment: i'm so sorry, there was a ')' missing :( take a look at the fiddle now :)

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, I found a bit different syntax, using additional var define which also works: http://jsfiddle.net/dQsnk/5/

Comment: This also works, but usually i prefer to use less var as i can :)

Comment: Less vars and more {,( makes code more hard to read and makes it looks like magic regular expression %)

Comment: yeah everyone have his strategy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<basefont>
```

> **Obsolete** This feature is obsolete. Although it is still supported by
>   browsers, its usage is discouraged in new projects. Try to avoid using
>   it.

**Summary**

> The HTML basefont element () establishes a default font size
>   for a document. Font size then can be varied relative to the base font
>   size using the  element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/basefont

> - HTML 3.2 supports the basefont element but only with the size
>     attribute.
> - The strict HTML and XHTML specifications do not support this element.
> - Despite being part of transitional standards, some standards-focused browsers like Mozilla and Opera do not support this
>     element.
> - This element can be imitated with a CSS rule on the  element.
> - XHTML 1.0 requires a trailing slash for this element: .